# XAML TextBlock Binding with "..." at the end if text is too long

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, textblock

I have an ItemsControl with TextBlock inside. 
The TextBlock's text is Binded but if it is too long, it is truncated. 
I have already calculated the maximum character limit (20) and I would like that if it does not exceed them it is binded regularly, otherwise it is truncated but with "..." at the end.
I think I know how to do in codebehind, but I would like to do it exclusively from XAML using (I think) the Style.

Comment: If you set texttrimming to none doesn't that just cut off text that won't fit? If that doesn't suit then substring the string in your viewmodel property or a converter.

Comment: @Andy 
If you mean this, the text is already cut because the textblock has a fixed length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` on your `TextBlock` that will give you the behavior you need automatically.

If you need to enforce that 20 character limit, you can set a `MaxWidth` on your `TextBlock` to a value that gives you the width you need and `TextTrimming` will do the rest.